# Cocoa Java application on iPhone

Tags: java, iphone, plist

I was playing around with the `plist` of an iPhone project in Xcode, and I noticed the key "Cocoa Java application" with values "YES" and "NO". What's this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not for iPhone. At one time, Apple created a "bridge" that let you access Cocoa from Java. Note, that's Cocoa, the Mac OS X framework, not Cocoa Touch, the iOS framework. I'm not sure what the status of the bridge is at this time, but it's [at least deprecated](http://www.osnews.com/story/11165), and possibly not supported at all.